# engine oil temperature sensor problems

Tags: honda, motorcycle, sensor

I'm Getting a dtc for the eot sensor low voltage. According to the manual this happens when the voltage is less than 0.07v.

The connector is plugged in properly. I have checked continuity between the connector and ecm at the appropriate pins and all is good. The reference voltage on the sensor with the bike turned on but not running is 2.66volts.
I've checked the battery voltage and all seems ok.

Any ideas on what could be causing it?

Comment: Two things: bad sensor; no oil pressure. I really don't know how to test the sensor in question, other than replacement.

Comment: BTW: What is the bike in question? Year/make/model/engine

Comment: It's a Honda msx 125 2015. The bike runs fine. The eot problem causes it to not start easily when it's cold which is annoying as I'm sure you can imagine.